# Can I build My Ubuntu One

Tags: server, ubuntu-one

Is it possible to install an Ubuntu One server in my personal data center, so that all the work that is done will not be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Once all the source code is released (server side currently isn't open source) then yes. But there's no guarantee that the community will maintain the code once it's open sourced. This is not to suggest any lack of faith in the community but that other open source options exist, more of which later. There are several alternatives that are worth exploring. A few are:

- [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/), if security is important to you but storage capacity and open code are lesser considerations;
- [Copy](https://www.copy.com/home/), if storage capacity is your most important consideration; and
- [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/), if open code is your most important consideration and you're willing to find your own hosting.

I'm using SpiderOak since I heard U1 was closing. Your question suggests ownCloud might suit your needs best.